# Correct folder path under TortoiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I check out .../Project to folder PROJECT. It contains sub-folder trunk. I accidentally move trunk contents to its parent locally and delete PROJECT's .svn also. I would like to re-map URL .../Project to .../Project/trunk so that I can work directly under trunk folder and dont have to checkout again to correct metadata. Checkout consumes time at my side.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You're wanting to do an [svn switch](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.ref.svn.c.switch.html) either via the command line or many SVN clients (i.e. Tortoise), expose this easily through the GUI. However, if you've deleted .svn folders (which help track the base version of files before modification), you may find you need to check out again.

Comment: +1, but I will add that if you only deleted the `.svn` folder for the top level, you can re-checkout that folder locally but non-recursively to get it back.

Comment: "svn switch" is helpful. But in my case, check-out is better. Thanks @TroyHunt

Answer (score 0):

you cant move folders like that in SVN.

have you tried to recheck it out ?

or

you can delete the folder from the svn, and them move it to its parent, and delete the hidden "svn" folder in it, then commit it again .